# How to get dictionary of df indices that links the same ids on different days?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I've following toy-dataframe:

```
    | id| date
--------------
0   | a | d1
1   | b | d1
2   | a | d2
3   | c | d2
4   | b | d3
5   | a | d3
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a'], 'date': ['d1', 'd1', 'd2', 'd2', 'd3', 'd3']})
```

I want to obtaining 'linking dicitionary', like this: `d = {0: 2, 2: 5, 1: 4}`,
where (numbers are just row index)

- `0:2` means link `a` from `d1` to `a` from `d2`,
- `2:5` means link `a` from `d2` to `a` from `d3`,
- `1:4` means link `b` from `d1` to `b` from `d3`

Is there some simple and clean way to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

d = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.index, x.index[1:])))
d = reduce(lambda d1, d2: {**d1, **d2}, d)  # or reduce(lambda d1, d2: d1 | d2, d)
print(d)

# Output
{0: 2, 2: 5, 1: 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k: v for _, x in df.groupby('id') for k, v in zip(x.index, x.index[1:])}
print (d)
{0: 2, 2: 5, 1: 4}
```

Comment: Second approach is really clean. Thanks!